# Hide lockscreen widget programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, lockscreen

I'm building a count down timer and want to have a lock screen widget for it. How ever when the timer is running, the widget doesn't make sense. Is there a way to hide it when not required? Ex. like what 'now playing' widget does for music players.